# Continuous injective curve from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ containing the interval $[0,1]\times {0}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I want to know if it is possible to have an injective continuous curve from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ whose image contains the interval $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ with $f(0)=(0,0)$. There is one trivial solutions, that is, go straight across the interval: $f(x)= (x,0)$. Let $f(t_f)=(1,0)$. We say two solutions $f,g$ are different if $f([0,t_f])\neq g([0,t_g])$.

Does there exist an example different from the trivial solution? i.e. the curve leaves the interval at some point before finishing.

If yes, please give a counter example. Otherwise, please put the solution in spoiler tags, I have been trying to solve this myself but I'm too worried there is a counter example.

My current idea is to look at the sup $t_0=\{t: \exists s: f([0,t])= [0,s]\times \{0\} \}$. Intuitively, to cover $(t_0+\epsilon,0)$, we have to come back later. We find a sequence of epsilons converging to zero such that the time of return does not converge to $0$. Then by continuity (+Bolzano weierstrass on epsilons) we get $f(\lim \epsilon_n)=(0,0)$ contradicting injectivity. Im having a hard time materialising the third sentence.

edit:

My solution:
Suppose $f$ is different from the trivial solution. Then we must have some $t'<t_f$ where we are not on the interval and so by continuity we can have an interval. Lets take a maximal one i.e. let
$$t_0 := \inf \{t: \pi(f(t))\neq 0, t\le t' \} $$
$$t_1 := \inf \{t: \pi(f(t))=0 \cap t\ge t'\}$$
Then by continuity,

- $t_0\neq t_1$
- $\pi_y(f(t_0)) = \pi_y(f(t_1))=0$ but $\pi_y(f(t)) \neq 0 $ for $t_0<t<t_1$

and by injectivity

- $\pi_x(f(t_0))\neq \pi_x(f(t_1))$

Some of the interval $(\pi_x(f(t_0)), \pi_x(f(t_1)))\times \{0\}$ may have been covered in $[0,t_0]$, however, not all of it otherwise $f(t_1)$ is an intersection. What was covered is, by continuity, a closed set therefore the complement in the interval is $(\text{open set in }\mathbb{R}) \times \{0\} $ in particular we have a "maximal" subset  $(a, \pi_x(f(t_1) ))\times \{0\}$ for which $(a,0)\in f([0,t_0])$. $(a, \pi_x(f(t_1) ))\times \{0\}$ must be covered in $f[t_1,1]$ therefore by continuity $\exists t_2\in(t_1,1]$ with $f(t_2)=(a,0)$, contradicting injectivity

Comment: You can just insert a loop at any point. Or make the curve continue after completing the interval. Or let it start somewhere else. Or... This is one of those cases where you shouldn't start thinking about the abstract symbolic stuff. Start geometrically, where you will immediately find a humongous amount of examples. Then pick one that you can easily translate to symbolic form.

Comment: What about a curve which traces out the unit squre? i.e. f([0,0.25]) = [0,1]x[0], f([0.25,0.5]) = [1]x[1,0], f([0.5,0.75]) = [0,1]x[1], f([0.75, 1]) = [0]x[0,1]. Clearly this f is distinct from the "trivial" example you laid out above, and also contains the interval [0,1]x[0]

Comment: @dsillman2000 Not injective, you hit the origin twice

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos your first example is not injective. the second is not different from the trivial example. the third doesn't satisfy $f(0)=(0,0)$

Comment: @janes good point, I'll modify my answer so it doesn't

Comment: For every strictly monotone bijection $\tau:[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$, the mapping $f(t) = (\tau(t), 0)$ is an example (which you'd regard as equivalent). There are no others (mod details) because a continuous injection on a compact set, such as the closed unit interval, is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang The images are homeomorphic, how does that imply they are not different under my definition?

Comment: If $\tau$ is an increasing bijection and $f(t) = (\tau(t), 0)$, the image of $f$ is $[0, 1]$; I understood the question to mean any two such are the same, but maybe I misunderstood the notation $t_f$. If you _do_ regard these examples as distinct, then ... they're distinct. <> Conversely, I claim (admittedly without having carefully written down details) there are no others, i.e., no examples whose image strictly contains the interval $[0, 1] \times \{0\}$. (I understood you want curves that start at $(0, 0)$ and end at $(1, 0)$...?)

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible, and here is a proof (don't look if you don't want to see!)

We recall the following facts about topological spaces:

- The image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact
- A compact subset of Euclidean space is closed and bounded (Heine-Borel Theorem)
- In a connected topological space $X$, the only open and closed sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$.

Now, let's say we have a function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ different from the trivial example whose image contains the required interval. By your definition, there is $s \in [0,1]$ such that $g(s) \not\in [0,1]\times\{0\}$. Since $g$ is continuous, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $g([s-\varepsilon, s+\varepsilon]) \cap ([0,1]\times \{0\}) = \emptyset$.

Moreover, $[s+\varepsilon,t_g]$ is compact, so $g([s+\varepsilon,t_g])$ is also compact, and therefore closed and bounded. $g([s+\varepsilon,t_g])\cap([0,1]\times\{0\})$ is therefore a closed subset of $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ (using the subspace topology). The subset $g([0,s-\varepsilon])\cap([0,1]\times\{0\})$ is also a closed subset of $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ by the same argument. Since the union of these two sets is the entirety of $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ by the previous paragraph, both are also the complement of closed sets and therefore open sets.

Since these two subsets are open and closed, and nonempty, they must both be the entire space $[0,1]\times\{0\}$. They are therefore not disjoint, and the map $g$ is not injective.

Comment: Hi, I haven't read your solution yet because im not sure mine is correct, would you mind checking mine first so i can accept?

Comment: @janes I'm a little confused by your solution. First, why must $f([t_1,1])$ contain $(\pi_x(f(t_0)), \pi_x(f(t_1)))\times \{0\}$ (i.e. why couldn't some of it be covered by $f([0,t_0])$?) Secondly, do you really mean $t_2 \in (t_0,t_1)$?

Comment: a) I overlooked this but I don't think it matters. Please see the edit. b) No, $t_2\in (t_1,1]$

Comment: @janes I believe your proof is valid!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative, as I understand your question. If you start at $f(0) = (0, 0)$, want $f$ to be continuous and that $f([0, 1])$ contains $[0, 1] \times \{0 \}$, **you have to start by tracing this line**.

Indeed, consider : $\{ t \in [0, 1], \pi_y(f(t)) = 0 \}$ where $\pi_y$ denotes the projection on the second coordinate. By continuity of $f$, this is a closed set and therefore a compact subset of $[0, 1]$. Each connected component of this compact is itself compact, and there are at most countably many. Now the image by $f$ of each such compact connected component is a compact interval by continuity.

By projecting on the $x$-coordinate, this means that you can write $[0, 1]$ as the countable disjoint (by injectivity of $f$) union of compact intervals. But this is impossible, unless there is exactly one such compact interval. (At least with the axiom of choice.) This mean that $\{ t \in [0, 1], \pi_y(f(t)) = 0 \}$ is an interval, and since it contains $0$ you are done.

Comment: Sadly I already spent a lot of time thinking about this idea. "... connected component ...  there are at most countably many" is false or needs more justification, there could be (uncountably many) singletons (E.g. the situation when x=0 in sin(1/x) with sin(1/0):=0. ). The rest of the argument collapses.

Comment: Indeed, I did not think about this... Thanks for correcting !

Answer (score -1):

One counterexample to your claim is the curve which traces out the unit square except for one side. This curve would be defined piecewise, by

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}(3t,0)&0\leq t < 1/3 \\
(1,3(t-1/3)&1/3\leq t<2/3 \\
(1-3(t-2/3), 1)&2/3\leq t \leq 1 \end{cases}
$$
Whose image looks like this:

[image: Unit square img]

Clearly, this curve contains $[0,1]\times[0]$ and is not the trivial solution you provided which contains only the interval. It is also injective, as every point in the image curve is associated with a unique domain point $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: $t_f= \frac{1}{4}$ and $f[0,t_f]=$ the interval therefore not different from the trivial example